# Divergent or not series?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, divergent-series

How tipe are this series? 
$$\sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac 1 {n^2\ln n}$$
But
$$\sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac 1 {n\ln n\ln(\ln n)}$$
I used Condensation Test, but I stack after that.
Thanks!

Comment: The condensation test works for both. Try again

Comment: I think you have some mistake here. $\frac{1}{ \log n}$ is undefined for $n=1$.

Comment: Probably its from 2, in my book its from 1.

Comment: You need to edit. Change the "$i$" in the sums to "$n$" and make it from $2$ to $\infty,$  not from $1.$

Comment: As mentioned by @Blazej, both are examples of applications of the [Condensation test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_condensation_test) in the wikipedia article.

Comment: For the second one use the condensation test twice.

Comment: Thanks, @Surb. Daniel, I edited the code and thanks a lot for your hints!

Comment: The cool thing about the second series is that the general term is the derivative of $\ln(\ln(\ln(n)))$ but probably not that useful in this context.

Comment: @DanielWainfleet, for the first, after apply the Condensation Test I got $\frac 1 {2^nnln 2}$. Now I can use that $\frac{1}{2^nn \ln(2)} <\frac{1}{2^n}$ and the last one is divergent?

Comment: For the first, you could do this by direct comparison to immediately recognize that since $n^2\ln n>n^2>0$ for all $n\geq e$ that it follows that $0<\frac{1}{n^2\ln n}\leq \frac{1}{n^2}$ for all $n\geq e$.  This directly implies then that $\sum\limits_{n=4}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2\ln n}\leq \sum\limits_{n=4}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2}$, and we know the sum on the right converges so the sum on the left does too.  Then remember that the sum on the left is the same as your sum except missing finitely many finite terms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $f(n)=1/n^2\ln n$ for $n\geq 2$.  Then $f(n)$ is decreasing. Now $0<2^nf(2^n)=1/(2^n\cdot n\ln 2)<1/2^n,$ and $\sum_{n>1}1/2^n$ converges, so   $\sum_{n>1} f(n)$ converges.

Let $g(n)=[n(\ln n)(\ln \ln n)]^{-1}$ for $n\geq 2.$ Then $g(n)$ is decreasing for $n\geq 3.$  And $$2^n g(2^n)=    [(n\ln 2)(\log n +\ln \ln 2)]^{-1}>[2\ln 2]^{-1}[n\ln n]^{-1}>0$$ for $n\geq 3.$  Applying the Cauchy condensation test to $[n\ln n]^{-1}$ shows that $\sum_{n>2}[n\ln n]^{-1}$ diverges, so $\sum_{n>1}g(n)$ diverges.

Note: It often helps to look for ways to simplify an intermediate step. E.g.  by comparing $2^ng(n)$ to $[2\ln 2]^{-1}[n\ln n]^{-1} ,$ as there is less calculation and detail when applying the condensation test to the latter expression.

Note: By repeated use of the condensation test, each of the series $\sum_{n>n_1} [n(\ln n)^A]^{-1},\; \;$ $\sum_{n>n_2} [n(\ln n) (\ln \ln  n)^A]^{-1},\;\; $ $\sum_{n>n_3} [n(\ln n)( \ln \ln n) (\ln\ln\ln n)^A]^{-1}$...(et cetera)... (where $n_1,n_2,n_3$ are large enough that the terms of the series are all defined).... converges for $A>1$ and diverges for $A\leq 1.$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

$$\frac{1}{n^2 \ln(n)} <\frac{1}{n^2} $$

For the second one, calculate $\int_2^R  \frac{1}{x \ln (x) \ln(\ln(x))}$ using the substitution $u=\ln(\ln(x))$.

Comment: I dont wanna use the integral test, its not teached in my school. Other idea, please?

Comment: Use the condensation test, twice.

Comment: Thanks, @ProfessorVector!